# MVC4 HTML5 video in IE10

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, video, internet-explorer-10

I have tried everything I possibly could, but I was not able to solve this. I am trying to display an mp4 video using an HTML5 video element in IE9 and IE10. In IE9 I get a blank square where the video is supposed to show and in IE10 it says "Invalid Source". It plays fine in Chrome.

The video displays fine within a simple HTML file, but not in my ASP.net MVC project, whether run locally or on a web server. I have the file placed in my root folder (same folder as the web.config)

Here is my code in my ASP.NET MVC index.cshtml:

```
<video controls style="position:inherit" >
   <source src="ExplainerVideo.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
</video>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure: Simple HTML - works in IE10 and Chrome; MVC App - doesn't work in IE, works in Chrome?

Comment: yes. that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking away the codec and letting the browser decide for itself whether it can play it or not.

e.g. `<source src="ExplainerVideo.mp4" type='video/mp4' />`

Failing that, try an absolute URL for the video as I've noticed this causing issues on IE before.

Comment: Thanks. Tried both those approaches. Interesting thing is, it says "Invalid Source", so it seems like it points to where the file is located... I have tried placing the file in the root, in the contents, but to no avail.

Comment: If you drag the video into the browser does it play?

Comment: it works fine. Ideally, I would like it to open in the div on the page.

Comment: That's very weird, as the browser can clearly play it. Do you have a test site at all I could take a look at?

Comment: Weird, as you say, it works fine in Chrome (and Safari) but not IE. It also doesn't work in Firefox (which would use the WebM or Ogg file). I suspect it's the file encoding. What did you use to encode them?

Comment: I just re-encoded the WebM from the MP4 using the Miro Video Converter and it now plays fine in Firefox. I also used Miro to re-encode the MP4 and it too now works fine in IE10.